# Query Statement in PHP has undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

I am attempting to write code that will edit a Single entry in a SQL database, the $num is the invoice ID number, I must be passing it incorrectly, because my console was showing an Undefined value for the idinvoice,

Now the console isn't showing any errors :/

Google and stack haven't yield much yet,

Here is my Javascript

```
$scope.saveEdit = function($param){

    $scope.list2 = { };

        if($scope.who == 'Dealer'){ $scope.list2.billTo        = 'Dealer';             $scope.billTo        = ''; }
        else                      { $scope.list2.billTo        = 'Customer';           $scope.billTo        = ''; }
        if($scope.billStart)      { $scope.list2.billStart     = $scope.billStart;     $scope.billStart     = ''; }
        if($scope.customerName)   { $scope.list2.customerName  = $scope.customerName;  $scope.customerName  = ''; }
        if($scope.dealerName)     { $scope.list2.dealerName    = $scope.dealerName;    $scope.dealerName    = ''; }
        if($scope.item)           { $scope.list2.item          = $scope.item;          $scope.item          = ''; }
        if($scope.price)          { $scope.list2.price         = $scope.price;         $scope.price         = ''; }
        if($scope.qty)            { $scope.list2.qty           = $scope.qty;           $scope.qty           = ''; }
        if($scope.cost)           { $scope.list2.cost          = $scope.cost;          $scope.cost          = ''; }
        if($scope.contractTerms)  { $scope.list2.contractTerms = $scope.contractTerms; $scope.contractTerms = ''; }
                                    $scope.list2.per           = $scope.per;           $scope.per           = '0';

    $http.post('DealerRec/writeInvoice.php?$num='+$param+'&action=writeEdit', $scope.list2)
        .success(function(data){ console.log("Data Written"); console.log(data); })
        .error(function()      { console.log("Data Not Written");                });
}
```

Here is my php file for connecting to SQL

```
switch($_GET['action']){
case 'writeInvoice':
        writeInvoice();
        break;
case 'fetchInvoice':
        echo fetchInvoice($_GET['num']);
        break;
case 'saveEdit':
        writeEdit($_GET['num']);
        break;
}

function writeEdit($num){

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$customerName  = $data->customerName;
$dealerName    = $data->dealerName;
$billTo        = $data->billTo;
$billStart     = substr($data->billStart,0,10);
$contractTerms = $data->contractTerms;
$item          = $data->item;
$price         = $data->price;
$qty           = $data->qty;
$per           = $data->per;
$cost          = $data->cost;

$qry = "UPDATE  invoice
        SET
          customerName  = '{$customerName}',
          dealerName    = '{$dealerName}',
          billTo        = '{$billTo}',
          billStart     = '{$billStart}',
          contractTerms = '{$contractTerms}',
          item          = '{$item}',
          itemPrice     = '{$price}',
          quantity      = '{$qty}',
          cost          = '{$cost}',
          sharePercent  = '{$per}'
              WHERE idInvoice ='{$num}'";

echo ($qry);

$qry_res = new Query($qry);
if ($qry_res) { $arr = array('msg' => "Invoice edited successfully!!!", 'error' => ''); }
else          { $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error in inserting record');      }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a check for `'writeEdit'` in that switch ?

Comment: `$num` in your JS is a `PHP` variable? `$_GET['num']` isn't going to be set as far as I can tell.

Comment: why you are using '{}' in idInvoice?

Comment: Num is set in the  $http.post statement right? in the URL(num=) + $Param + url

Comment: As mentioned by @chris85, you are passing the parameter `$num` as part of the query string, change it to `num` or (not recommended and you'd have to use single quotes) access it like `$num= $_GET['$num'];`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as follows

change to this

```
    $http.post('DealerRec/writeInvoice.php?action=saveEdit', $scope.list2)
         .success(function(data){ console.log("Data Written"); console.log(data); })
         .error(function()      { console.log("Data Not Written");                     });
}
```

and this

```
case 'saveEdit':
        saveEdit();
        break;
```

and finally this

```
$price         = $data->price;
$qty           = $data->qty;
$per           = $data->per;
$cost          = $data->cost;
$num           = $data->idInvoice; <----------------------
```

These functions now work. Thank you all for your help.